# Regex pattern matching for input type time

Tags: angularjs, regex, html

To check whether input type "time" field is completed (09:00am) I have used a regular expression.

```
ng-pattern="\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm]))"
```

But in the same regular expression I want to check whether the input field is empty. For further information, time field can be empty or completed (ex: )(09:30am)

Can anyone help me regarding this..

Comment: `^|((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm]))$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an `ng-pattern`, you need to use

```
ng-pattern="/^(?:(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5]\d\s*[AaPp][Mm])?$/"
```

and if you need to avoid leading/trailing spaces, also add `ng-trim="false"`.

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qwhd3X/2).

The `(?:...)?` optional non-capturing group is a wrapper for the whole pattern that becomes optional, i.e. can match an empty string.

The `^` anchor will only match at the start of the string, and `$` will anchor the match at the end of the string, so that an entire string should match.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is looking for a regex for European time format (00:00-23:59), as i was, here is the regex for that:

`^(?:1[0-9]|2[0-3]|0?[0-9]):[0-5]\d{1}?$`

Hope this helps somebody save a minute or two.